# Sourcing .bashrc does not enable use of nvm

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant

I'm trying to set up a shell script to run in the context of a user account after the creation of a virtual machine using vagrant; I am a windows user so I've limited exposure to bash scripting. I'm using virtual machines to set up linux boxes so I can use the superior OS base before I make the switch to Mac later on this year ;-)

To the problem: I'm attempting to install nvm using it's install script; the website states that after installing nvm you must reload your bash shell. I'm of the understanding I could instead source my `.bashrc` without having to reboot the shell (which would be inconvenient). Here's the shell script that I'm using:

```
## NVM
# install nvm
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | bash
# copy nvm config 
cp /vagrant/dotfiles/.nvmrc ~/.nvmrc
# let bash see the new bash profile
source ~/.bashrc
# add nvm
nvm install
```

This is all run in the context of a user's account (no sudo, but it shouldn't be necessary). The issue being is that once we get to `nvm install`, it would appear that sourcing the `.bashrc` has not exposed `nvm` to the bash shell, and it fails because it cannot find `nvm`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-53-generic i686), which utilizes bash + `.bashrc` for this.

The console output is below.

```
==> workspace: => Downloading nvm from git to '/home/vagrant/.nvm'
=>  workspace:
==> workspace: Cloning into '/home/vagrant/.nvm'...
==> workspace: * (detached from v0.25.4)
==> workspace:   master
==> workspace: => Source string already in /home/vagrant/.bashrc
==> workspace: => Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm
==> workspace: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 12: nvm: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hah I'm doing exactly the same thing and was stumped by the same thing. Source should work... but it doesn't.

Solution:
**source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh**

Going right to the source (no pun intended) seems to have fixed it.

Also something else to keep in mind is that using vagrant up/reload --provision runs whatever provision script as root, but if you vagrant ssh into your machine, it drops you into the vagrant user which wont have ~/.nvm

/root/.nvm
vs
/home/vagrant/.nvm

Comment: your latter comment is what was the issue; I was running the provisioner as privileged. Woops. I should have copied it to `/usr/share`

Comment: If my comment was a solution, would you mind marking it so?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I must have forgotten to fix this.. there you go.

Comment: Cleaner way: source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh